Using Powershell to pull out Active Directory user property from a different domain with ADSI
I am trying to get user properties e.g. path, givenName, sn etc. from a different domain.
This code works fine if I run this in the Active Directory Server Domain Controller:
$userId = 'UserID'
$UserDN = (Get-ADUser -F {SamAccountName -eq $userId})
$Command = [ADSI] "LDAP://$UserDN"
$Command | select * | format-list

Then I tried to use the cmdlet Get-StoredCredential and Get-ADUser to run the script locally hoping to get the same results but it's just returning blank properties:
$Credential = $(Get-StoredCredential -Target targetdomaincredential)
$userId = 'UserID'
$UserDN = (Get-ADUser -Server ADDCX -Credential $Credential -F {SamAccountName -eq $userId})
$Command = [ADSI] "LDAP://$UserDN"
$Command | select * | format-list

Appreciate any help or if someone can point me in the right direction, that would be great!

If the computer you're running this from is not joined to the same domain or a trusted domain than the one you're connecting to, then your computer won't know which server to contact for that DN. So you need to tell it by putting the domain DNS in the LDAP path in this format: LDAP://server/dn
Since you're using the ADDCX-Credential variable in the -Server parameter, I'm guessing that's it? If correct, your ADSI line should look like this:
$Command = [ADSI] "LDAP://$ADDCX-Credential/$UserDN"

But I'm also curious why you're using Get-ADUser and ADSI? They're both doing the same thing. You can use the -Properties parameter of Get-ADUser to have it return the values you want in one network request rather than two.

Hi! Sorry there was just a typo in ADDCX-Credential, it is actually ADDCX which refers to the server name. I will test out your recommendation $Command = [ADSI] "LDAP://ADDCX/$UserDN". I needed to use ADSI and Get-ADUser together because using Get-ADUser alone wont allow me to achieve my goal which is to pull out the value of "allowlogon" property - it seems to be known bug based on this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/48009/deny-this-user-permissions-to-log-on-to-remote-des

Okay, i just test $Command = [ADSI] "LDAP://ADDCX/$UserDN, it isn't working either. It's returning blank properties too.

As an additional note, when i use $Command = [ADSI] "LDAP://ADDCX/$UserDN, it is locking out the credential i am using due to number of incorrect username/pw.

@user3596261 Are you working remotely? When was the last time you authenticated on your computer while connected to the network? I wonder if your password is expired and you don't notice because you're not connected to the network when you login to your computer.

Yes, working remotely. My password is not yet expired, in case it gets expired, my colleague can easily reset it for me.
